# Unable to play mp4 file on iOS7

Tags: ios, c#-4.0, xamarin.ios

I'm currently trying to get an mp4 to play in my app. The MP4 plays fine in vlc (basic check to ensure it's not broken).

The code I'm using looks like this

```
private void startAnimation()
    {
        using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                player = new MPMoviePlayerController(NSUrl.FromFilename("Graphics/videos/noaudio-data-download.mp4"))
                {
                    AllowsAirPlay = true,
                    Fullscreen = true,
                    ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill,
                    RepeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One,
                    SourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File,
                    ShouldAutoplay = true,
                    ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen,
                };
                player.View.Frame = View.Bounds;

                View.AddSubview(player.View);
                View.BringSubviewToFront(player.View);
                player.PrepareToPlay();
                player.Play(); 
            });
        }
    }

    private void stopAnimation()
    {
        player.Stop();
        player.Dispose();
    }
```

All I get is a black screen and the incredibly unhelpful error

```
2014-01-05 22:00:44.995 ftrack2ios[85614:80b] _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

From what I've read on here and other forums, this error can be down to a pile of different reasons, most of them seem to be down to resizing.

The error occurs on a device as well as on the simulator. I'm not sure if this in iOS 7 issue as it used to work on iOS 6 after some playing around.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I found that

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23203292#23203292

http://www.techisky.com/how-to/play-mp4-on-ios-7-ipad.html